# bootstrap carousel higher than images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to implement a carousel into my website.
It should be fullscreen and then scale down on smaller devices. The images are responsive and everything works fine, my only problem is that the "real" carousel doesn't scale down when it goes lower than 1200px. So that means the prev- and next-icons and the gradient on the right and the left of the images stay the same size as on a big desktop.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Previous


    
    Next

and of course I implemented this before the  tag

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to make the gradients and icons scale down with the image?
Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

One of the carousel containers has `min-width: 1200px;` or `width: 1200px` - Double check the CSS